# tableview constraisnts in iphone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: swift, constraints, tableview

I am using a tbaleview and want to make sure they looks good in both the smaller and larger iPhones ( 6 and 6 plus), but even after setting all the constraints on the left right and top to 0, I still see this. Any thoughts ? Thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: What do your constraints look like?

Comment: I deleted all the constraints in that view and it still shows the same.

Comment: If you want your UI to adapt to different screen sizes you have to use AutoLayout constraints. The system can't figure out how you want your views to be laid out on it's own.

Comment: this tutorial helped me get it right. Had to set tableview to be horizontal in container and set the constraints mentioned in this video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this tutorial helped me get it right. Had to set tableview to be horizontal in container and set the constraints mentioned in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ES69XgBDgeo&t=180s

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you accidentally set the width constraint to a constant. Delete the width constraint and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like might be you have given fix width constrain, 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTQiW.png)

Remove this kind of constrain if exist and done